# backend application consumes all RAM but no memory leaks were found

Tags: node.js, docker, memory-leaks, nestjs

I recently deployed my NestJS backend application to Render and I mentioned that all available RAM is gone after some time for my service.

[image]

It can work fine for quite some time, consuming no more than 500mb of RAM which is what I expect to see, but then something happens and memory starts to leak. `top` says my node process is using 1.4g of memory:

```
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                              
     60 render    20   0 2883236   1.4g  56492 S   0.3   2.3  17:27.66 node
```

But then I started my application with `--inspect` flag to make a heap snapshot, and surprisingly it showed that heap size was only 65 megabytes while top says `1.4g`:

[image]

That I also see in VSCode debugger extension:
[image]

I thought that puppeteer might be an issue, so I killed every single chrome processes by PID from top output, and it only freed around 80mb of RAM. What could be the issue here and why my RAM usage is so high?

Comment: if the memory keeps growing then you have a memory leak. We can't tell much other than that, I guess

Comment: @MicaelLevi how can I detect it if recommended way is not pointing out to a leaking spot?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what type of project you are developing, but recently I also had a memory leak problem in a system that uploads files.

First, to find out what is causing the memory leak, you will need to monitor which request is being called in your API that is causing this problem and debug and analyze your project's code.

I noticed that you are using the NodeJs `--inspect` flag to analyze, try to do a descending sort by the `Retained Size` column and start analyzing what is inside each array, probably there are arrays or objects that could point to some library installed in your project that may be causing a memory leak for you to perform debugging.

The problem I was having was with the `Mongoose` library, at one point in my code it was necessary to open the connection to the database and it was not being closed. What can also cause a memory leak is the `Blob` and `Buffer` of files, in my case I had to delete the `Buffer` when finishing an upload and also ending the read/write operation of a stream that used `Blob`.

I won't be able to tell you what your problem might be in your project, but it will really be necessary to carry out debugging and code analysis.